# How to run multiple methods after db.event.listens_for(MODEL,"after_....")

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello i currently have a database model that uses `db.event.listens_for()` as triggers.

for example

```
@db.event.listens_for(Order, "after_delete")
def update_table_status(mapper, connection, target):
    # print('Checking if the table contains orders')
    table = Tables.__table__
    orders = Order.query.filter_by(tables_id=target.tables_id).filter(Order.checkout_id == None).all()
    # print(orders)
    # print(target.tables_id)
    if len(orders) == 0:
        # print('No orders associated to the table.')
        connection.execute(table.update().where(table.c.id == target.tables_id).values(active=0))
        # firebase_table(target.store_id)
    else:
        # print('Orders still associated to the table.')
        connection.execute(table.update().where(table.c.id == target.tables_id).values(active=1))
        # firebase_table(target.store_id)
```

is there a way to group together multiple methods and perform a batch operation with only one use of the decorator?

A class maybe?

```
@db.event.listens_for(Order, "after_delete")
class OrdersAfterDelete:
    def DOA(self):
        #do stuff

    def DOB(self):
        #do stuff
```

Comment: Why don't you just write a function that calls the other functions and decorate that?

Comment: that could work. But is there a way to implement it by a class?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I haven't used SQLAlchemy in a couple years, that's why I just made a comment.

Comment: I thought of a potential solution for your problem. I've made it an answer so I could format the code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try something like this:

```
@db.event.listens_for(Order, "after_delete")
class AfterDeleteListener(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.DOA(*args, **kwargs)

    def DOA(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff
```

This is essentially the same as my suggestion to make a function that calls the functions, but you can group all the methods together this way.

Comment: how would this look like with the decorators included and a simple method?

Comment: I edited to look a little more like I was thinking. Since I don't have Flask set up, I can't test it out myself, but I'm assuming that the `listens_for` function will call the class the same as it would with a function, passing the arguments to the initializer so you'd be able to access the arguments the same way you would from a function, but within the `__init__` method.

Comment: it does not work. it gives the error.     `super(AfterDeleteListener, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`

Comment: Oh, yea. Just remove the `super` call. It's not necessary

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.